# Recommendation for a multichannel wireless mic system

Tags: recommendations, microphone, wireless

I'm having trouble choosing a multichannel wireless mic system.  It will be for a live variety show done for a private audience, just something to help the older folks hear a little better and maybe to pipe into a consumer quality digital video camera.  It'd need to have six to eight channels and lapel or lavalier mic's.

The thing is, we don't have a lot of money to invest and a lot of the more affordable sets I'm finding are getting pretty bad reviews.  For instance, I found a Pyle Pro PDWM8900 for $240, but the reviews were pretty brutal.

Is there anything under $400 worth having?  We don't need awesome sound quality, since it will be mainly for speaking only.  It also doesn't have to be able to withstand daily use - a few times a year is all we're looking for.

Is there any hope for me?  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Not at this budget. Your best bet is to look at some Sennheiser g3 gear but this will be difficult on your budget. Sorry.

Comment: Sometimes the truth isn't fun, but that doesn't change the facts.  Thanks.